# How can I change API url on express from a react component

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have the following external JSON API:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Product Number 1",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Product Number 2",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Product Number 3",
    }
  ],
  "nextPage": "someapiurl.com/products?page=2"
}
```

The nextPage link on API has the same structure above, but with different products and a link to page 3. And then page 4, 5, 6, ..., has the same structure.

I'm fetching it to an express server and using a proxy to use the data on React.

This is the express server I have:

```
const express = require('express');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    let url = 'someapiurl/products?page=1';
    fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()).then((contents) =>
        res.send({
            products: contents.products,
            nextPage: contents.nextPage
        })
    );
});

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

and then my react component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const IndexPage = () => {
    const [ products, setProducts ] = useState([]);
    const [ nextPage, setNextPage ] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const url = '/api';
        fetch(url).then((response) => response.json()).then((contents) => {
            setProducts([ ...products, ...contents.products ]);
            setNextPage(contents.nextPage);
        });
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            {products.map((product) => <p>{product.name}</p>)}
            <button>Load More</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default IndexPage;
```

What I expect is when I click 'load more', the state nextPage is sent to express and then changes the variable url. My intentions is that the products from 2nd page on API are added to products state and then rendered to the page.

I can change it to axios to query data, if it's better.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried? And are you familiar with AJAX? https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html. You could use an ajax request get the data from your api everytime you click the 'load button'

Comment: I have no familiarity with AJAX, but if it's better I can have a try

Answer (score 0):

See this example below:

```
class Feed extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: [],
      visible: 2,
      error: false
    };

    this.loadMore = this.loadMore.bind(this);
  }

  loadMore() {
    this.setState((prev) => {
      return {visible: prev.visible + 4};
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(
      res => res.json()
    ).then(res => {
      this.setState({
        items: res
      });
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
      this.setState({
        error: true
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <div>
          {this.state.items.slice(0, this.state.visible).map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <div key={item.id}>
                  <span>{index+1}</span>
                  <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                  <p>{item.body}</p>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
          {this.state.visible < this.state.items.length &&
             <button onClick={this.loadMore} type="button">Load more</button>
          }
        </section>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Feed />, document.getElementById('feed'));
```

Comment: You could also use Axios Library for API Requests instead Fetch. https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Why should he do that? What does that do? Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks, but the api is divided in pages. It's not a huge api page with data. I have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

According to the React documentation the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method is a good place to load some initial data.

> [**componentDidMount**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)
>
> ...*If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request...*
> You **may call setState() immediately** in componentDidMount(). It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen...

So this is where you would fetch your first product page. E.g. `someapiurl.com/products?page=1`
You may also want to set the next page (`nextPage`) value as a `nextPage` state property.
Maybe something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch('someapiurl.com/products?page=1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
       this.setState({
         products: json.products
         nextPage: json.nextPage
       })
    })
}
```

Now you can render your products according to the `products` state property.

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <ul>{ this.state.products.map( product => (<li key={product.id}>{product.name}</li>) ) } </ul>
    <button onClick={this.onNextPageClick}>next</button>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Use the `button` to call a function to load the next page which will then change the `products` and `nextPage` state properties. Maybe just add a function to take care of fetching your data and simply pass the `nextPage` URL to it.

```
loadNextPage = url => {
    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
       this.setState({
         products: json.products
         nextPage: json.nextPage
       })
    })
}
```

So whenever the button is clicked the `onNextPageClick` handler would call `loadNextPage` with whatever value `this.state.nextPage` currently is set to.

```
onNextPageClick = event => {
    this.loadNextPage(this.state.nextPage)
}
```

You may also want to take a look at [Introducing Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html)

React hooks will let you do all of the above without using classes or lifecycle methods.

> [**Hooks at a Glance**](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html)
>
> *Hooks are a new addition in React 16.8. They let you use state and other React features without writing a class.*

Here is an example using React hooks which you can adapt to your needs. It is simply loading a `username` by increasing a value on every click. Since I do not have any pages I thought this would kind of mimic your scenario. I am sure you will get the idea.

```js
function LoadStuff () {

  const [userId, setUserId] = React.useState(1);
  const [userName, setUserName] = React.useState("")

  const fetchUser = url => {
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
      setUserName(json.name)
    })
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetchUser('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+userId)
  }, [userId])

  const loadNextUser = () => (userId < 10) ? setUserId(userId + 1) : setUserId(1)

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div>
        <p>{userId}</p>
        <p>{userName}</p>
      </div>
      <button onClick={loadNextUser}>Load next user</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <LoadStuff />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.8.6/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.8.6/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: Great @DavidDomain, it gave me a light. I have updated my question